# Pass arguments from php function issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress plugin. In plugin, a user first add a slider and then add images of relevant slider.

First i make this with shortcode. User enter the short name of the slider in the shortcode and images slides of relevant slider like this `[foo_slider slider=slider_one]` or `[foo_slider slider=slider_two]`.

Now i "also" want the snippet, that user can add snippet else shortcode in the code like this `echo wp_foo_slider(slider_two)`. But i dont get that.

Please guide me, how can i do this.

Here is my Code That works for shortcode:

```
<?php
function wp_foo_sliders($atts) {
    global $wpdb;
    $tbl_sliders = $wpdb->prefix . "foo_sliders";

    ob_start();
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'slider' => '',
                    ), $atts));

    $get_sliders = $wpdb->get_results("Select * From $tbl_sliders Where slider_shortname = '$slider'");
?>
    <div class="foo_main_slider">
    <?php
        foreach ($get_sliders as $get_slider) {
            $slider_id = $get_slider->slider_id;
    ?>
    <div class="foo_slider_img">
    <?php
        $get_slider_image = $wpdb->get_results("Select * From ".$wpdb->prefix."foo_images Where 

slider_id = $slider_id Order By image_order ASC");

        foreach ($get_slider_image as $foo_img) { 
    ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $foo_img->image_path . $foo_img->image_name; ?>" alt="">
     <?php
        }
        }
        return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode("foo_slider", "wp_foo_sliders");
?>
```

I also try this by my own `<?php echo wp_foo_sliders("slider_two") ?>` or `<?php echo wp_foo_sliders(slider_two) ?>`, in code and when i refresh the browser only `<div class="foo_main_slider"> </div>` appears and no images show.

**Edit**: I want that user can use short code `<?php echo do_shortcode('[foo_slider slider=slider_one]'); ?>` or user can use snippet `<?php echo wp_foo_sliders("slider_two") ?>`, only shortcode is working, snippet not work.

What i make mistake please help me.

Comment: You want to use that short code in your PHP file manually. Is that the case ?

Comment: Your shortcode is called `foo_slider`, not `wp_foo_sliders`

Comment: wp_foo_sliders() is my function name where i call images of a slide

Comment: True, but this function is modified through the shortcode. Did you check out the Shortcode API in the codex how to use a shortcode and how to use the attributes to modify what the shortcode returns

Comment: hmmmmmm no, i dont check this

Comment: Your answer is locked up on that page, and your key will be the attributes. :-). A must read

Comment: No @PieterGoosen this is not my solution :-)

Comment: beacause this whole article is for shortcode and i want function that return the whole content .... and i get this by my own :-)

Comment: and i answered this question after complete testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i get my solution by my own.

I make a new function for this:

```
<?php
function foo_sliders($foo_short_name) {
    global $wpdb;
    $tbl_sliders = $wpdb->prefix . "foo_sliders";

    $get_sliders = $wpdb->get_results("Select * From $tbl_sliders Where slider_shortname = '$slider'");
?>
    <div class="foo_main_slider">
    <?php
        foreach ($get_sliders as $get_slider) {
            $slider_id = $get_slider->slider_id;
    ?>
    <div class="foo_slider_img">
    <?php
        $get_slider_image = $wpdb->get_results("Select * From ".$wpdb->prefix."foo_images Where 

slider_id = $slider_id Order By image_order ASC");

        foreach ($get_slider_image as $foo_img) { 
    ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $foo_img->image_path . $foo_img->image_name; ?>" alt="">
     <?php
        }
        }
    ob_start();
    return $foo_short_name;
    return ob_get_clean();
}

?>
```

And in theme code:

```
<?php foo_sliders(short_name) ?>
```

and its work great

Answer (score 1):

When you call the shortcode function directly, you are passing a string to it. When you use the shortcode way WordPress will convert the arguments into an associative array.

Try refactoring your code

```
if( is_array( $atts ) ) {
    //Called using shortcode so $atts is an array
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'slider' => '',
                    ), $atts));

} else {
    //Function called directly so $atts is a string
    $slider = $atts;
}
```